# Change user maildir to custom location upon creation of the user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, useradd

I use Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS . How to change the location of the Mailbox /`home/user/Maildir/` to `/Location/Mail/`?

I don't have to create home directory for that user. 
I did some changes in the `/etc/default/useradd` file and `/etc/login.defs` but when I create a new user doesn't reflect(mail directory is created in /home/user/ directory).

So I need to create a user of which its mail directory points to  `/Location/Mail/` by default. 
 
 I also use postfix. If I can change default user mail directory in postfix, it is also okay for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the location of Mailbox, include the below line in the file '/etc/postfix/main.cf'

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /Location/Mail/
```

If you don't want to create home directory(i.e non Unix Account user) then include the below line in the file '/etc/postfix/main.cf'

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/userlist
```

Once you added these files in Postfix, add the required user's you wish to configure the mailbox,
In File /etc/postfix/userlist,

```
user1@example.com   user1
user2@example.com   user2
```

...with your required no.of users...

If you do need to create user's default maildir to /Location/Mail/ instead of /home then modify in the file '/etc/default/useradd'

```
Home=/Location/Mail
```

This will create Mailbox in the path /Location/Mail//Maildir/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set the `mail_spool_directory` to the new directory:

```
sudo postconf mail_spool_directory=/Location/Mail/
```

For this to work, `home_mailbox` must be empty:

```
sudo postconf home_mailbox=
```

However, your server might be set up to use a different command to write deliver mails to a user.  The `mailbox_command` parameter might have been set (e.g. `mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) or a transport using the Dovecot MDA could be defined in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`.

In other words:  The above should work, but this really depends on the rest of your setup.

Comment: How do I change the mailbox directory from User home dir to another default dir?

Comment: The two commands above should be sufficient to change the default directory using postfix.  As already stated, it's hard to tell without knowing your exact setup.  Add the content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to your question if you need more details.